# iOS private API call to bring app to the foreground

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

Is there any way to programmatically bring an iOS application that's currently running in the background to the foreground? Note that this is an enterprise iOS app for non-jailbroken devices, so private API calls are fine.

I've tried a number of solutions already, including registering a custom URL handler and calling `openURL` from the background task, but it seems that `openURL` calls are ignored from background tasks. Is there a lower-level private API call that's used by `openURL` internally that I could use?

Other approaches I've tried include those mentioned at [Launch other application without URL schema in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693796/launch-other-application-without-url-schema-in-iphone/11693879#11693879) but those don't seem to work from background tasks either.

Comment: Ben, I asked very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531544/show-some-ui-from-background-in-audio-player-or-voip-app-on-ios I am still trying to figure out how to do this. No luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] launchApplicationWithIdentifier:@"" suspended:NO];
```

You'll need to set the `com.apple.springboard.launchapplications` entitlement to `YES` as well for it to work.

Comment: This requires a jailbroken device.

Comment: Do you need to self sign the file as I cant deploy to the device due to the entitlement