# how to open another application from background using Custom URL scheme in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, iphone-privateapi

I want to develop an Enterprise Application. It will run in the background continuously and from the background i want to open an another application. Its like toggle between two application. I have implemented forever background running with help of Location services which is working fine and also updating the location from the background but it is unable to execute openURL method.

Please suggest something.Thanks

Comment: This is for non-jailbroken phones, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible!

You can use these links only.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

I will extend a little bit on MobiDevCom answer.

I haven't found a good publicly known solution.

The direct approach (trying to open something from background using all kinds of public or private API) ends up requiring all kinds of entitlements. I tried at least dozen of things about a year ago and reverse engineered quite a lot of iOS components.

The only idea which I found was usage of MDM Guided mode (however, a device needs to be supervised and enrolled into MDM for that).

BTW. Here is the question which I asked - [Show some UI from background in audio player or VOIP app on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531544/show-some-ui-from-background-in-audio-player-or-voip-app-on-ios)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to bring an application in foreground from background using MDM guided mode?

Comment: I tried it mainly on iOS 6, so it may be not applicable to iOS 7 and even less applicable to iOS 8. The answer is "yes" for iOS 6. However, it wasn't very stable back then (meaning: a device quite often got to some weird states).