# Opening application with url scheme from a background application

Tags: ios, url-scheme

My iOS application is in background.
A beacon event wake up this application.

On the wakeup I need to open an other application from an url scheme

- If my first application is active, the other application is correctly started
- If my first application is in background, the other application is NOT started

Is it possible ? what is the solution

In the iPhone logs console I have the following message:

> NSUnderlyingError=0x14bf85370 {Error
>   Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=3 "Application com.x.x is
>   neither visible nor entitled, so may not open URLs."
>   UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=Security,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application com.ticatag.tibe is neither
>   visible nor entitled, so may not open URLs.}},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.orange.horizons.radio"
>   failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service
>   delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Security ("Application com.x.x
>   is neither visible nor entitled, so may not open URLs").}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303871/how-to-open-another-application-from-background-using-custom-url-scheme-in-ios
might help

Answer (score 3):

**Not Possible**, When you open URL, It actually open the resource at given URL and if that url schema is handled by some other app - That app invoked. You cant Open Resource when Your app is not in foreground.